# Unreal Engine 4: Problem with attach camera to spring arm

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have problem with attach camera to spring arm in Unreal Engine 4. Please help me.

ACharacter.h:

```
protected:

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category="Components")
        UCameraComponent* CameraComp;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "Components")
        USpringArmComponent* SpringArmComp;
```

ACharacter.cpp:
Code:

```
ACharacter::ACharacter()
{

    SpringArmComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<USpringArmComponent>(TEXT("SpringArmComp"));
    SpringArmComp->bUsePawnControlRotation = true;
    SpringArmComp->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);

    CameraComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("CameraComp"));
    CameraComp->SetupAttachment(SpringArmComp, USpringArmComponent::SocketName);
}
```

After run, camera is on the floor and don't follow the character (player). And camera isn't attachment to spring arm (I see it in BP).
I watched a lot of tutorials on YT, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you provide more of the .h for ACharacter, including what class you are deriving from. I'm confused because there is already a class called ACharacter, so I'm curious to see what you are deriving your class from.

The most obvious problem with the code you've shown is that you have not set your RootComponent to anything, but since I don't know what class ACharacter derives from I'm not sure if it's an issue or not.

Comment: Thanks for reply. After restart UE4 problem is solved.